# Highlight all instances of a word in a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a Sub that finds all instances of the word "uM" in a single cell and change the font to blue. Here's a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMwwj.png) of what I want the code to do, and what my code outputs.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Highlight_uM()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Attention As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Counter As Integer


Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Set Attention = WS.Cells.Find(What:="Attention", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
      'Find Attention range
    For Each Cell In Attention
        For Counter = 1 To Len(Cell)
            If Cell.Characters(Counter, 1).Text = "u" Then
                Cell.Characters(Counter, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 42
            End If
        Next
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

As you can see from my code, it only selects `.Text = "u"`. If I change it to `= "uM"`, the sub doesn't do anything. Any tips on how to amend my code to highlight every instance of the entire word "uM" in the cell?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo because you need to change the `1` to `2`, otherwise `Characters(Counter, 1)` returns a single character so that `= "uM"` will always be false.

Comment: But the redundancy of your outer loop remains =)

Comment: ^ Because `Range.Find` can only return a single cell.

Comment: @BigBen Amazing! It was just that easy. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
Sub highlightCellCharacters()

Range("C1").Select

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("C1:C6")

For Each Cell In rng
   Dim Counter As Integer

For Counter = 1 To Len(Cell)
   If Cell.Characters(Counter, 2).Text = "uM" Then
      Cell.Characters(Counter, 2).Font.ColorIndex = 3
   End If
Next

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Next Cell

End Sub
```

This will work for cells C1 to C6

Comment: I know exactly which youtube video this is from; I modeled my code after it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSZa4sYfGFw

Comment: Why did you changes it?

Comment: I want it to work for my range, which isn't in C1 to C6.

Comment: as long as you change your range to something valid it's supposed to work